# Android webView in fragment shows blank page

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, webview

I'm trying to show a web page in a fragment that is inside a viewpager, but when I swipe to that fragment, it is empty and shows a blank page.
I have searched this a lot and all solutions I found suggest the code I have.
The app has internet permission (and it works, because it loads data from DB)

This is the fragment layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ubiqme.ubiqme.fragments.ReservationFragment">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_reservation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the fragment source:

```
public class ReservationFragment extends Fragment {

public ReservationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_resevation, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview_reservation);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.ubiqme_web));
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    return rootView;
}

}
```

This fragment (reservationFragment) is added to the viewPager here:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TicketsFragment(), "");
    adapter.addFragment(new KmFragment(), "");
    adapter.addFragment(new ReservationFragment(), "");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The result is this:
[image]

Hope someone can help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel so dumb about this, but I just found out that the url I was trying  to open in the webView (and the others I tried) had no "http://" before the url.
After adding it the webview works like a charm.

Sorry

Answer (score 0):

check this code I don't know this code will solve your problem , if your tab size is 3 then put 2 as parameter,otherwise put number of tab -1 as parameter

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```